# How do i compare csvs which don't have headers for format and data difference in java

Tags: java, string, csv, time, compare

I have a pair of similar CSV's without header rows.I have to compare them for format and data differences,how do I parse them so that i may know data type for the parsed string values.i.e, I have to identify if the parsed string is a date or time or currency or normal string.Currently I am using Apache Commons CSV parser( without header constructor)but I am unable to compare the CSV's as I don't know which value corresponds to which type?please help.

Comment: Educate the publisher of those poorly-formed data files?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the first line of each csv and use regular expressions to sort them into the different categories. If you're not looking for a super clean way, you can maybe just check if certain special characters are contained within the string like the currency symbols and sort them out that way. If it doesnt have a currency symbol then it could be a date or normal string. If it doesnt have '-' either then it's a normal string.

Comment: Now ,Suppose i have header rows in both the files but they may be present in some other language.like date may be present in column named "Datum" which is german for date etc.Now, how do i extract different fields as data type in java are defined as date ,time,string ,number.For instance how do i extract date and time and balance specifically ?I cannot use regular expression for currency/balance.(and date /time may have numerous formats for which i have prepared a list)

Comment: You've got to turn the string into a data type. For balance, simply parse the string into a number. As for DateTime, if you know the used format, you can just create a new date time by extracting the information you need from the string.